# My Service is running in standby but only if USB is connected. Why?

Tags: java, android

I have created (i'm a noob!!!!) a good app that use a service to do some periodic operations.

**When the phone is connected to pc via USB** (using eclipse with device connected) during test, **the service run even in stadby**, in the best way possible.

I can see it in logcat and by the result operation...

But **when the phone is disconnected the service is running only if the phone is wake up**!

How i can solve it without wakelock ?

I mean obtain something like RADIO FM, understand? ;-)

Thanx to all friends!

Answer (score 1):

> When the phone is connected to pc via USB (using eclipse with device connected) during test, the service run even in stadby, in the best way possible.

That is probably because the device is not actually in "standby".

> How i can solve it without wakelock ?

You can't.

> I have created (i'm a noob!!!!) a good app that use a service to do some periodic operations.

Use `AlarmManager` and something like my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) for this.

> I mean obtain something like RADIO FM, understand? ;-)

Android does not have "RADIO FM".

Comment: No man...my Huawei IDEOS instead HAVE an app called "Radio FM" that run in background also in standby, so that you can listen music with less battery usage...

Comment: If i said that the phone is in stand by when connected to pc via usb, why is not? Trust me, reading logact i can see that the phone is in standby....anyway you didn't trust me about this and about radio fm (search before speak if you don't know...) -1

Comment: @Lork: "my Huawei IDEOS instead HAVE an app called "Radio FM"" -- the IDEOS is a phone. Android is an operating system. Android does not have "RADIO FM". "If i said that the phone is in stand by when connected to pc via usb, why is not?" -- by definition, if you are seeing LogCat messages during the period of time in question, the CPU is still powered on, and so the device is not in "standby". The screen might be off, but that has little to do with the state of the CPU.

Comment: Can you explain why if my phone is running an "aLogcat" app (downloaded from market) and is usb disconnected, register the events of others services even if phone is in standby?????

Comment: @Lork: Perhaps aLogcat holds a `WakeLock`. Please contact the author of "aLogcat" for questions about "aLogcat".

Comment: Maybe...but a last answer: services like Gmail or others that work even in standby mode how they can do that without being interrupt? Thanx

Comment: @Lork: "services like Gmail or others that work even in standby mode how they can do that without being interrupt?" -- they hold a `WakeLock`.